# Recursively search all subfolders for png images and convert them to one mp4 video

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ffmpeg, video

I have timelapse camera that is recording a png picture every 30 seconds. The timelapse system makes a subfolder that has the date as its name and then each subfolder contains png files which are named based on the time they were taken.

How could I recursively loop through each subfolder and compile an mp4 video file out of the sequences? I have both Windows and Linux computers so the solution can be for either operating system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg

Comment: And with this command you can recursively list all the PNG files and copy them to a single (target) directory: `find <top_dir> -name *.png -exec cp {} <target_dir> \;`

<target_dir> should not be a subfolder of <top_dir>